# Getting a file's location in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im trying to pick a file in a file explorer using intent.
here is my code:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE );
```

it works fine and picks a file but I need to get the picked file's location. what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean with location and why do you need it? You get an uri. So use the uri.

Answer (score 0):

Once you select a file this method will be called automatically.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
It will give you the bitmap

```
Bitmap bm = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and here `data.getData()` gives you the uri